# Database connection according to drop-down list

Tags: laravel-7

I am an interesting project, but I have a problem that I would like to solve before starting.

I am in the process of building an extranet for a franchise. The franchise therefore has several franchisees in several geographic sectors. They will have to connect from the same login page (same application). In this page there will be a region selector There will be a database per franchisee (constraint imposed)

Do you know a method so that depending on the region selector, the user connects to the chosen base?
for example:
region paca => base 1
region center => base 2
etc,
I know Laravel relatively well, but I have never had the problem so far. If anyone has an idea or would have had the same scenario, I would be very grateful if they would share their info.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Salut, c'est un site en anglais. Je t'invite donc à poster ton message en anglais :)

Comment: Yes^^ really sorry

Comment: No problem, you edit your question so it's perfect. I just add answer

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to achieve what you want, it depend of what is duplicate.

Just, you have to store the information somewhere, and to have an object that say "option", for example:

```
"regionA": {
   "db": "dbA",
   "name": "Region A"
}
```

Just manage it as you want, that's why I write it in JSON.

1. Each region have a different server

You just redirect people on good website, and each website use it's own database

2. One server, but different schema in database

Use different connection, according to the region. For example, the region "A" use the database "software_a".

For example, one will do:

```php
DB:connection("db_regionA")
```

Another will do:

```php
DB:connection("db_regionB")
```

3. One database, one table, all rows says it's region

Just in `SELECT` request, such as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE region = "A"
```

Comment: OK . how I manage the authentication on the different bases:
They are all the same.

They will all have user tables, etc,

I must necessarily modify a provider? model? controller? so that the authentication is done on the selected base.
Will I have to prefix all my requests with DB: Connection?
My case is your expemple 2.

Comment: For the exemple 2, you just have to log on one base, and all table are the same. It's just the area in where you are working which is different

Comment: Ok I will be more specific.

I have 2 connections:
DB_CONNECTION = mysql
DB_CONNECTION = mysql2
  mysql is the default.
So the login is done naturally with mysql

But If the user selects mysql2, LoginController must use mysql2.

I must necessarily make a modification, in the Logincontroller so that the user uses the selected database and not the default one ..

Comment: Sure. It depend of how you organize it, but yes you have to change the selected db according to current region